# need to print list from top to bottom instead of bottom to top

Tags: python-3.x

atm program, needs to keep history of last 5 transactions. updates but prints most recent transaction at bottom instead of top.

transactions is an empty list at the beginning of the program, starts off empty and fills as the program is being used.

```
if option == 5:
    if len(transactions) <=0:
        print("No History")
    if len(transactions) > 5:
        lower_bound = int(len(transactions)) - 5
        upper_bound = lower_bound + 5
        transaction_counter = 1
    for element in range(lower_bound, upper_bound):
        print(str(transaction_counter) + transactions[element])
        transaction_counter = transaction_counter + 1
  else:
       transaction_counter = 1
       for element in range(0, int(len(transactions))):
           print(str(transaction_counter) + transactions[element])
           transaction_counter = transaction_counter + 1
```

Actual Output:

1. deposit $200 into savings
2. deposit $5 into checking
3. transfer $200 from checking to savings
4. withdrawal $20 from savings
5. balance inquiry

Expected Output:
1. balance inquiry
2. withdrawal $20 from savings
3. transfer $200 from checking to savings
4. deposit $5 into checking
5. deposit $200 into savings

Comment: Expected output is supposed to print same way as Actual Output.

Comment: reverse the list before printing?!?

Comment: i tried that, doesn't work

Comment: `for element in range(lower_bound, upper_bound):` Did you try: `for element in range(upper_bound, lower_bound):`

Comment: yes, i tried everything backwards to no avail

Comment: Use splicing. `my_list[-5:]`

Comment: where do you recommend i put that in the code?

Comment: change the second `for` loop to: `range(-5, 0, -1)`

Comment: Also looks like you are dealing with a stack or queue. You may want to look into using a `deque` instead of a `list`.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the step -  try changing to: `for element in range(upper_bound, lower_bound, -1):`

Comment: i appreciate the help but i attempted all of these to no avail

Answer (score 2):

Stop using indexing, use elements themself:

```
w = "withddraw"
d = "deposit"
t = "transfer"
i = "inquire"
sv = "savings"
ch = "checking"

hist = []
hist.append( (i,))
hist.append( (i,))
hist.append( (d, 200, sv))
hist.append( (d, 5, ch))
hist.append( (t, 200, ch, sv))
hist.append( (w, 20, sv))
hist.append( (i,))

print(hist)

for num,what in enumerate(hist[-5:][::-1],1):
    print(num, what)
```

Output:

```
# the list 
[('inquire',), ('inquire',), ('deposit', 200, 'savings'), 
 ('deposit', 5, 'checking'), ('transfer', 200, 'checking', 'savings'), 
 ('withddraw', 20, 'savings'), ('inquire',)]

# the output of sliced last 5 reversed elements
1 ('inquire',)
2 ('withddraw', 20, 'savings')
3 ('transfer', 200, 'checking', 'savings')
4 ('deposit', 5, 'checking')
5 ('deposit', 200, 'savings')
```

Explanation of the list slicing to get last 5 elements reversed:

```
hist[-5:]              # takes the last 5 elememnts of your list == the last 5 actions
hist[-5:][::-1]        # reverses the last 5 elements
enumerate(.., 1)       # enumerates the iterable starting at 1 returning tuples (num, elem)
```

and the `print` outputs it ...

Comment: Instead of `[-5:][::-1]` you can just do a single splice: `[:-6:-1]`. Less readable but faster

Comment: @err I leave that imn the comment ;)  I like the readable one better even if its more work